# lowercase a string with struts?

Tags: java, struts2

I have a need to lowercase some text coming back from an external web service in all caps. I need to do this with with struts and not Javascript. Is it possible?

I am pretty new to Struts and I didn't really find anything searching the tag reference.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe with the toLowerCase() java.lang.String method?

Comment: +1 also for simple things like this you should look at the underlying language to see if it is possible. As an example googling for "convert string to lowercase struts" probably won't get you much but "convert string to lowercase java" should reveal the answer.

Comment: @Flash84x : It is surprising, how much can go wrong, If you know just little less, then you do now.

Comment: This one saved my day. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean in the jsp? Then the following OGNL in a property tag will work fine:

```
<s:property value="myStringValue.toLowerCase()"/>
```

PS: +1 to Enrique but the OP may not have known OGNL expressions of type string could use string methods.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for - I wanted to just convert a String to lowercase on the JSP without any additional processing in the Java actions.

Answer (score 0):

Some beginners are surprised, that

```
String exVal = "SOMETEXT";
exVal.toLowerCase();
```

does not work. This is because `Strings` are immutable in Java, so you need to use

```
String exVal = "SOMETEXT";
exVal = exVal.toLowerCase();
```

or just `"SOMETEXT".toLowerCase()` before use.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the JSTL: `${fn:toLowerCase(myString)}`